# <trigger multiple-target VBA script actions by formula changes in any of the targets

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and managed to get to work a script where it is possible to control the colors of objects by changing a table.

At this point I have 7 objects (A ~ G) and I created variables for 6 different colors (1 ~ 6). These numbers should keep being expandable. Especially the number of definable objects I expect to rise to multiple hundreds. The purposes is to create large dashboards / visualizations and being able to control them from a spreadsheet.

The problem is that a formula in D12 ~ D18 doesn't trigger the colors to change. Only manual input on the cell triggers it. I have been searching a long time, but I can not find a solution. The main problem is the number of targets. Does anyone PLEASE have any thoughts?

Example file: [Test-Objects.xlsm](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Apqa4VZDg6ZlgRw78O4Mxo8Ei94U)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("D12:D300")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

        Select Case Target.Address(False, False)
               Case "D12"
                    shapename = "objectA"
               Case "D13"
                    shapename = "objectB"
               Case "D14"
                    shapename = "objectC"
               Case "D15"
                    shapename = "objectD"
               Case "D16"
                    shapename = "objectE"
               Case "D17"
                    shapename = "objectF"
               Case "D18"
                    shapename = "objectG"
        End Select

        With testobjects.Shapes(shapename).Fill.ForeColor
             Select Case Target
                    Case Is = "1"
                         .RGB = RGB(180, 0, 0)
                    Case Is = "2"
                         .RGB = RGB(220, 0, 0)
                    Case Is = "3"
                         .RGB = RGB(255, 95, 83)
                    Case Is = "4"
                         .RGB = RGB(255, 165, 129)
                    Case Is = "5"
                         .RGB = RGB(0, 97, 240)
                    Case Is = "6"
                         .RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240)
             End Select
        End With
    End Sub
```

*Above code is from the sheet and the following from the Module:*

```
Sub whatever()
    ShapeColor = Abs(Range("F2") = 0) * 10 + Abs(Range("F2") = 40) * 3
    With testobjects.Shapes("CustShp").Fill
    .ForeColor.SchemeColor = ShapeColor
    .Solid
    End With
End Sub
```

I wish you all great last few days of 2016!

Comment: what is `With testobjects.Shapes(shapename).Fill.ForeColor` suppose to be ? if you just use `With Shapes(shapename).Fill.ForeColor` since the shapes are in the worksheet where this code lies, it works

Comment: The `Worksheet_Change` event does not fire when a formula calculates a different value, so if D12:D18 are formulae then they are not the cells you want to watch for a change.  Which cells are the ones which cause D12:D18 to change value?

Comment: Hi YowE3K, thanks you for your question. The source is a different sheet with 200+ items/objects, with many more columns holding information on each of them. There will be an algorithm deciding for the ultimate categorisation for each of them, which must result in the color of the objects. In the end I think the best thing to do is to place an "update" button next to my visualisation which will trigger the VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited 2** to switch to a `WorkBook_SheetChange()` approach

as per your further clarifications you must handle "sensible" cells coming from different sheets and hundreds of shapes

so you may want to:

- switch `to Workbook_SheetChange()` event handler to be placed in `ThisWorkbook` code pane

  this will allow you to intercept any cells changing in any worksheet
- have a way to recognize a "sensible" cell

  either you define a collection of them (a `Dictionary` could suit this) or you *mark* them in a distinctive way, for instance being the only cells with yellow background color

  since your example has "sensible" cells yellow colored I'll go with this latter

so here's a possible code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range

    If Target.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Interior.ColorIndex <> 6 Then Exit Sub '<--| exit sub if changed cell is not a "sensible" one
    With testobjects '<--| reference your "shapes" sheet
        For Each cell In .Range("D12:D300").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers) '<--| loop through its "no. (select):" cells containing a number resulting out of a formula
            .Shapes("object" & cell.Offset(, -1)).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = GetRGB(cell.Value) '<--| update current "no (select)" corresponding shape color
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

as you see I assumed, as per your example, that shapes are named after "objectX" where "X" is taken from the cell one column left of corresponding "no (select)" value

this way you don't need any array to store shapes names into and simply get them out of `testobjects` sheet `Shapes` collection "on the fly"

While as for the `GetRGB()` function you have the already seen following alternatives:

- Select case approach

  ```
  Function GetRGB(val As Integer) As Long
      Select Case val
          Case 1
              GetRGB = RGB(180, 0, 0)
          Case 2
              GetRGB = RGB(220, 0, 0)
          Case 3
              GetRGB = RGB(255, 95, 83)
          Case 4
              GetRGB = RGB(255, 165, 129)
          Case 5
              GetRGB = RGB(0, 97, 240)
          Case 6
              GetRGB = RGB(0, 176, 240)
      End Select
  End Function
  ```
- `Choose()` function approach

  ```
  Function GetRGB(val As Integer) As Long
      GetRGB = Choose(val, RGB(180, 0, 0), RGB(220, 0, 0), RGB(255, 95, 83), RGB(255, 165, 129), RGB(0, 97, 240), RGB(0, 176, 240))
  End Function
  ```

  where you have to be sure that `val` must range from 1 to the number of choices listed in the function, otherwise it'd return a Null value and Shapes(shapesArr(iShp)).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = GetRGB(.Cells(iShp + 1).Value)` would will error out

  if such exceptions are possible, you may want to add some `If`s or stick to the `Select Case` approach or try the following alternative
- `Dictionary` approach

  ```
  Function GetRGB(val As Integer) As Long
      With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") '<-- use a late binding "on the fly" dictionary instantiation 
          .Add 1, RGB(180, 0, 0) '<--| associate "key" '1' to "Value" 'RGB(180, 0, 0)'
          .Add 2, RGB(220, 0, 0) '<--| same as above
          .Add 3, RGB(255, 95, 83)
          .Add 4, RGB(255, 165, 129)
          .Add 5, RGB(0, 97, 240)
          .Add 6, RGB(0, 176, 240)
          GetRGB = .item(val) '<--| return the value associated with 'val' "key" 
      End With
  End Function
  ```

  that'd return a zero (i.e. *black* color) should `val` not match any of the hard coded `keys`

Comment: Hi user3598756, incredible thanks for your work-around! Indeed this works perfectly as a test. But in real life I have some additional major problems:
1) i want to create a sensible cell (updated button) in another sheet (because the data should be retrieved from there to make it possible to edit and sort). 
2) when creating a list of shape names bigger than 100 or so, the line is full and I don't get more shape names "objects" accepted. At this point I collected more than 200 shapes.

Comment: btw: I think adding to the 'sensible cells' another or extra solution is to create an "update" button to manually trigger the shapes color update.

Comment: @cyatheaceae, see edited answer to match your further clarifications. let me know

Answer (score 0):

The code for the `Worksheet_Change` event doesn't need the  `testobjects` as a prefix, since the `ActiveWorksheet` default is where this code lies, and where the shapes are placed.

Since you already restricted the `Range` to "D12:D300", you can later just use `Select Case Target.Row` since you already minimized the `Range` to Column D.

```
Option Explicit

Public testobjects As Worksheet


Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim shapename As String

    ' setting the testobjects to "Shhet2" >> modify to your sheet with the "objects"
    Set testobjects = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("D12:D300")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Select Case Target.Row
        Case 12
             shapename = "objectA"
        Case 13
             shapename = "objectB"
        Case 14
             shapename = "objectC"
        Case 15
             shapename = "objectD"
        Case 16
             shapename = "objectE"
        Case 17
             shapename = "objectF"
        Case 18
             shapename = "objectG"
    End Select

    With testobjects.Shapes(shapename).Fill.ForeColor
         Select Case CLng(Target.Value)
            Case 1
                 .RGB = RGB(180, 0, 0)
            Case 2
                 .RGB = RGB(220, 0, 0)
            Case 3
                 .RGB = RGB(255, 95, 83)
            Case 4
                 .RGB = RGB(255, 165, 129)
            Case 5
                 .RGB = RGB(0, 97, 240)
            Case 6
                 .RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240)
         End Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shai Rado, thank you for responding. The prefix was there because I intend to work with different sheets. I have now uploaded a test file and added the link in the original post above. And of course implemented your feedback. Please note that your comment doesn't change my question.

Comment: then you need to post the rest of your code, where do you define `Public testobjects As Worksheet` , and where do you set it to your sheet ?

Comment: this is the whole code. You can see yourself in the file I uploaded.

Comment: I am using Excel 2010 (not 2013), I can't open the code also using the web. Anyway, see edited code (i added a declaration of `testobjects` and also `Set` is to "Sheet2" >> modify to your sheet's objects

Comment: I am not sure how I get this to work yet... It's probably due to my lack of competences in VBA. Sorry for that!